# How to troubleshoot an unhandled win32 exception in a Delphi 2010 application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, unhandled-exception

I'm running Delphi 2010 Professional on an XP Pro machine. I've been working on a program for several days. Each time I run the program on my development machine it runs fine or so I thought. I run the program from within the IDE and it runs fine. I run the program from the output directory (outside the IDE) and it runs fine. I've had no issues anytime I run this program on my machine.

So, to simulate the customer experience, I copied the .exe file onto a memory stick and then copied it to a completely different machine. When I ran the program on that different machine I get an unhandled win32 exception.

Here is the error dialog:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| An unhandled win32 exception occured in ZilchStd.exe [984]. Just-In-Time     |
| debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed       |
| debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time  |
| debugging can be enabled from the Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.      |
|                                                                              |
| Check the documention index for "just-in-tim debugging, errors' from more    |
| information.                                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've never had this happen to me before. How do I troubleshoot this error?

Comment: If this is an error on startup, it may be a dependency issue, and you may well be best off debugging with Dependency Viewer in Profile mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [MadExcept](http://www.madshi.net), which will allow you to view a stack trace and more infromation about the error. It's free for non-commercial use (meaning testing your app like you did, but not distributing it as part of your app), and a commercial-use license is extremely useful and affordable.

You can even configure `MadExcept` to email you bug reports from your end users, which can include detailed environmental information like hardware configuration and system library versions.

There are other debugging tools available like the JCLDebug functionality included in [Jedi](http://delphi-jedi.org) and commercial products like [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com); I've never used either of them, so I can't commment comparitively.

Comment: I've used all three.  With madExcept 4, the advantage is back in MadExcept's corner.  EurekaLog is a fabulous product, too, but MadExcept's free-trial and free-for-non-commercial use make the the winner.  JCL debug is great as far as it goes, but isn't "batteries included" (no pre-build send-exception dialog and mail-send code) so its recommended for Software Craftsmen (and women) who like to build things themselves.

Comment: @Warren, thanks for the added comparison info. I've peeked into the JCL stuff, but figured it was lacking in the features that MadExcept provides, and as you said the trial and free non-commercial use make it a no-brainer. :-)

Comment: @Warren madExcept support for x64 is pretty crucial and thankfully Mathias delivered on that. Just in time for me, otherwise I'd have had to try out EurekaLog. Do you know if the JCLDebug stuff supports x64?